# Cannot apply Kotlin JVM plugin using pluginManagement block in Gradle project

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I'm setting up a simple Kotlin program with Gradle Kotlin Scripts. The initial `build.gradle.kts` file and the `settings.gradle.kts` files are very simple:

`build.gradle.kts` file:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.4.10"
}

group = "edu.nju.alex.wang"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
}
```

`settings.gradle.kts` file:

```
rootProject.name = "Barabra"
```

What I'm trying to do is to use the `pluginManangement` block to control the version of the Kotlin JVM plugin. So I changed the code into this.

`build.gradle.kts` file:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
}

group = "edu.nju.alex.wang"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"


dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
}
```

And `settings.gradle.kts` file:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    plugins {
        id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.4.10"
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Barabra"
```

However, when I try to execute Gradle tasks, it reported an error:

```
* Where:
Build file '/home/jue/Storage/Barbara/Barabra/build.gradle.kts' line: 1

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.4.10'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.4.10')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    MavenRepo
    BintrayJCenter
    Google
```

Am I doing something wrong or this just won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of your issue can be found here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories

> ```
> pluginManagement {
>     repositories {
>         maven(url = "../maven-repo")
>         gradlePluginPortal()
>         ivy(url = "../ivy-repo")
>     } 
>  }
> ```
>
> This tells Gradle to first look in the Maven repository at
> ../maven-repo when resolving plugins and then to check the Gradle
> Plugin Portal if the plugins are not found in the Maven repository. **If
> you don’t want the Gradle Plugin Portal to be searched, omit the
> gradlePluginPortal() line**. Finally, the Ivy repository at ../ivy-repo
> will be checked

In your case you have added some repos in the `repositories` ( google, jcenter, mavenCentral) but you did not add `gradlePluginPortal` which is the default place to resolve Gradle plugins from.

And it seems that `org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm` plugin in version `1.4.10` is not (currently?) available in other repositories than `Gradle Plugins repository`.

*So, how to fix this*: either remove the entire `repositories` block from `pluginManagement` (if you don't need to resolve plugins from your own specific repos) or add `gradlePluginPortal()` in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Most common cause I found was with the version of the org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm plugin. Find the correct latest version of the plugin [here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm) and change the version in build.gradle and let it reload.